# Compile a specific obj in a Visual Studio Project from the Command Line?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, command-line

I want to compile `file.obj` from the commandline.  Within the IDE, if I'm viewing `file.cpp`, I can click on Build -> Compile (or just hit Ctrl-F7), and it will compile just the file.obj object.  I would like to be able to do this from the commandline.  Ideally, something akin to:

```
vcbuild project.vcproj Debug file.obj       // not a valid command
```

I have looked at the documentation for `vcbuild`, `msbuild`, and `devenv`.  I've also experimented with all three, but I cannot find a way to do this.  I can find a way to build an entire project, but that's not what I want.  I want to build a specific source file.  `/pass1` tells vcbuild to just compile (not link), but it compiles the entire project.

I also looked at using `cl`, but that is just the compiler.  In order to use it, I would have to know all the right parameters to pass to set up my environment correctly.  All that is automatically taken care of with msbuild/vcbuild.

With Makefiles, I could always do `make file.obj`, and it would properly set path, include dirs, etc.

Any options for this?  Is there an automated way to extract the appropriate settings from the `.vcproj` file, and pass them to `cl`?

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work?

Comment: @RobotMess It cannot be done from the commandline.  But it can be done within a Visual Studio macro.  So, for my needs, I was able to create a macro that did what I needed, compiled the .obj, took action based on success/failure, and continued to do other things as well.  I'll see if I can find the macro and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using cl is the way to compile single files from the command line. Like you say, it requires/allows you to specify exactly the options you want to use. All the options!

If you actually don't want to do that, why not use the IDE to have it done automagically for you? Why do it the hardest way, if you don't like that?

Comment: I do use the IDE for general development.  However, I'm trying to write an automated utility, and it would require repeatedly compiling an individual source file.

Comment: @Tim: you can also do _that_ from the IDE (assuming VS) by right-clicking the source file and then choosing "Compile". Otherwise cl.exe and perhaps a small (NMake) make file is the way to go ...

Comment: Automated.  Right-clicking is a user action.  I need an automated way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to compile the project, run the **visual studio command line** and call **msbuild**.

Example:

```
MSBuild.exe MyProj.proj /property:Configuration=Debug
```

this will compile the MyProj Project from the current directory.

more info on msbuild
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574.aspx

Or if you need to build a single file you can use **cl** as stated above. You can see all the parameters passed by visual studio to **cl** if you go in the properties of the project. Usually under:

**Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Command Line**

and for linking:

**Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Command Line**

Comment: that builds the entire project, which is not what I need.

Comment: Ok, modified answer, you should be able to copy all the needed options this way

Comment: In order to use `cl`, I would have to know all the right parameters to pass to it.  Yes I could look them up in visual studio, but this is entirely manual, and would have to be done for every file (or at least every project).  I'm looking for an automated way.

Comment: It should be done for project only. Do you really have so may projects that extracting the settings is a problem ?